# Writing function for User Defined Contrast Enhancement?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

My problem is to implement a custom contrast enhancement for the raster images. Its not a linear enhancement, it is based on a logarithmic function.

I thought I can update the renderer block like we can do for the data provider. But it seems the writeBlock is available only for the data provider.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
rdp = layer.dataProvider()
block = rdb.block(1,extent, cols, rows)
```

This block gives the actual values from the raster. Not the ones from the renderer.

How do I write a function for custom Enhancement?

Answer (score 2):

For implementing a custom contrast enhancement for raster images you need to define several things. Assuming you have a raster with a **QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer** and you want a **QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer**, to implement a custom contrast enhancement for the raster images you need a color list of colors (as **ColorRampItem** objects) generated on a logarithmic function basis and its map values associated. I assumed both of them arbitrarily in my code. You also need a **QgsColorRampShader** and a **QgsRasterShader** objects.

Complete code is at follows:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QColor

layer = iface.activeLayer()
renderer = layer.renderer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()

#classes
classes = [1323, 1881, 2440, 2998]  #in your case map values associated to 
                                    #colors based on a logarithmic function

#assuming that these colors were produced with a logarithmic function
colors = [ QColor('green'), QColor('red'), QColor('blue'), QColor('brown')]

color_list = [ QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(classes[i], colors[i])  for i in range(4) ]

myRasterShader = QgsRasterShader()
myColorRamp = QgsColorRampShader()

myColorRamp.setColorRampItemList(color_list)
myColorRamp.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
myRasterShader.setRasterShaderFunction(myColorRamp)

myPseudoRenderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(provider, 1, myRasterShader)

layer.setRenderer(myPseudoRenderer)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

My raster looks as follow:

[image]

After running above code at Python Console of QGIS 3.4 I got result of following image:

[image]

Comment: I am want to implement the contrast Enhancement function for QgsSingleBandGrayRender/QgsMultibandColorRender, similar to the one given in raster toolbar. I have written the following script, but on executing it on the python console, the image disappears.